# Remove Orphaned OneNote Notebook

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am using OneNote 2013, and have a few network notebooks (not OneDrive) open.  However, at some point the network guys moved the server, and now I have an orphaned notebook that will not sync, move, or close.  It causes OneNote to take a long time to open.  Google keeps telling me to sign into OneDrive, but I do not have OneDrive, nor was this notebook ever attached to a OneDrive account.

So far I have tried

- Closing the notebook
- Moving the notebook
- Removing the notebook from the recent list

The first two items end up trying to sync the notebook, which of course fails, and then it just sits there.  Please help.

Comment: Ask your IT department to fix their error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it (thanks to the [Microsoft Answers forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_win10/remove-orphaned-onenote-notebook/259ce46f-c190-40c1-918d-13e80cc7c97e?tm=1489078953750)).

1. Run (Start Run)
2. onenote.exe /safeboot
3. Delete notebook cache

That closed all open notebooks, and then I could re-add the ones I needed.